# R tibble: Col-1 difference to last row where Col2 is "ch2"

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset in long format, where time events (column 1, numeric) were logged for 2 channels (column 2, ["ch1","ch2"]). 
Time values for `ch=ch1` have the actual data I would like to make a histogram of.  
Time values where `ch=ch2`, are start-events or maybe better called reset-triggers. 
I want from the events with `ch=ch1` the difference  of the `time`-value to the last time-value of `ch=ch2`.

A naive approach is to iterate rowwise, set a variable `startEvt` to `time` if `ch` is 2 and substract it from `time`. However, this is very inefficient...

What is the correct way of doing this with dyplr or in general?

```
tdat=data %>% ungroup() %>% arrange(time)
startEvt=0
for(i in 1:nrow(tdat)) {
    if(tdat$ch[i]==2){
        startEvt <- tdat$time[i]
    }
    tdat$time[i] <- tdat$time[i]-startEvt
}
```

example `data`

```
time    ch      wanted output
0       ch1     0
1       ch2     1
3       ch2     3
5       ch2     5
5       ch1     0
5       ch1     0
7       ch2     2
8       ch2     3
12      ch2     7
13      ch1     0
15      ch2     2
```

Comment: Is "column 1" `time` and "column 2" `expected`? It looks like your loop is calculating the `time` columns so maybe col1-2 are `ch` and `expected`? It's a little unclear.

Comment: Please review this question and try to phrase it more clearly. As currently written it presupposes familiarity with your situation and does not clearly define what you are starting with and what logic you want to implement to get to the answer.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you for the comment. Well, it was already my third draft... I tried again to make it a bit more clear, but it is hard to explain it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
tdat %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(ch == "ch1" & lag(ch, default = "") == "ch2")) %>%
  mutate(result = time - min(time)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here, I count how many cumulative times we've switched from a ch2 to a ch1, group based on that count, and compare each time to the first time within that group.

```
# A tibble: 11 x 5
    time ch    wanted   grp result
   <int> <chr>  <int> <int>  <int>
 1     0 ch1        0     0      0
 2     1 ch2        1     0      1
 3     3 ch2        3     0      3
 4     5 ch2        5     0      5
 5     5 ch1        0     1      0
 6     5 ch1        0     1      0
 7     7 ch2        2     1      2
 8     8 ch2        3     1      3
 9    12 ch2        7     1      7
10    13 ch1        0     2      0
11    15 ch2        2     2      2
```